# Getting the NullPointerException: "Cannot invoke "ParkingSpace.getSpaceNum()" because "pl.parkingLot[5]" is null"?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am working on a parking lot project in Java, and I am getting the following error message when I run my program: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "ParkingSpace.getSpaceNum()" because "pl.parkingLot[5]" is null at ParkingLot.main(ParkingLot.java:67)`

I do not understand why `pl.parkingLot[5]` is `null`, as I thought I had initialized a `ParkingSpace` at every index of the array parkingLot with a for a loop.

I thought that when I used a for loop in my class constructor for ParkingLot to give values to the array `parkingLot` calling `parkingLot[5]` would not result in `null`.

Also, I expected this program to run and print 5 on one line to the console and 4 to the next line, but running the program results in a NullPointerException.

Here is my code for the ParkingLot class:

```java
public class ParkingLot {
    ParkingSpace[] parkingLot;
    int numSpaces;
    int numFloors;

    ParkingLot(int numSpaces, int numFloors){
        this.numSpaces = numSpaces;
        this.numFloors = numFloors;

        ParkingSpace[] array = new ParkingSpace[numSpaces];
        parkingLot = new ParkingSpace[numSpaces];
        char currentFloor = 'A';
        for(int i = 0; i < numFloors; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++){
                parkingLot[j] = new ParkingSpace(j, currentFloor, false);
                if(j<4){
                   parkingLot[j].isCompact = true;
                }
                j++;
            }
            currentFloor++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    ParkingSpace enterLot(boolean com){
        ParkingSpace returnValue = new ParkingSpace(0,'A', false);
        for(int i = 0; i < numFloors; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++) {
                if (!parkingLot[j].isOccupied) {
                    if (com) {
                        returnValue = parkingLot[j];
                    } else if (i > 3) {
                        returnValue = parkingLot[j];
                    } else {
                        j++;
                    }
                } else {
                    j++;
                }

            }
            i++;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    void leaveLot(ParkingSpace space){
        for(int i = 0; i < numFloors; i++){
            if(i == space.floor){
                for(int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++){
                    if(j == space.spaceNum){
                        space.isOccupied = false;
                    }else{
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ParkingLot pl = new ParkingLot(6, 6);

        System.out.println(pl.parkingLot[5].getSpaceNum());
        System.out.println(pl.enterLot(false));
    }
}
```

Here is the ParkingSpace class:

```java
public class ParkingSpace {
    int spaceNum;
    char floor;
    boolean isCompact;
    boolean isOccupied;

    ParkingSpace(int spaceNum, char floor, boolean isCompact){
        this.spaceNum = spaceNum;
        this.floor = floor;
        this.isCompact = isCompact;
        isOccupied = false;
    }

    int getSpaceNum(){
        return spaceNum;
    }
    char getFloor(){
        return floor;
    }
    boolean getCompact(){
        return isCompact;
    }
    boolean getOccupied(){
        return isOccupied;
    }
    void setOccupied(boolean value){
        isOccupied = value;
    }
    String toAString(){
        char compact;
        char occupied;
        if(isCompact){
            compact = 'C';
        }else{
            compact = 'N';
        }

        if(isOccupied){
            occupied = 'X';
        }else{
            occupied = 'O';
        }

        return(floor + spaceNum + " (" + compact + " " + occupied + ")");
    }
```

Comment: It appears that you don't quite understand how the [`for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) works.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you increase i and j in the loop bodies? You initialize every second level and space 0, 2, 4. Levels 1, 3, 5 are not initialized. Just remove i++ and j++ from your constructor:

```
ParkingLot(int numSpaces, int numFloors) {
    this.numSpaces = numSpaces;
    this.numFloors = numFloors;
        
    ParkingSpace[] array = new ParkingSpace[numSpaces];
    parkingLot = new ParkingSpace[numSpaces];
    char currentFloor = 'A';
    for(int i = 0; i < numFloors; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++) {
            parkingLot[j] = new ParkingSpace(j, currentFloor, false);
            if(j < 4) {
                parkingLot[j].isCompact = true;
            }
            //j++;
        }
        currentFloor++;
        //i++;
    }
}
```